# Finding a 60s UK movie by picture of 2 men

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to recognize a movie by a screenshot.

I think this is a British 1960s movie.

[image]

Comment: Now I'm curious about what's being censored. `Go to work on an egg` is classy :)

Comment: [It's a shirt about to lose a button](http://www.tcm.com/mediaroom/video/278190/Bedazzled-Movie-Clip-Routine-Mischief.html). This is probably from an online quiz.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Bedazzled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedazzled_%281967_film%29) from 1967 in which Peter Cook is the devil and offers a young man (Dudley Moore) 7 wishes. Here's a frame from the same scene:

[image]